# Take average of conditional entropy function over different value of p

Tags: probability, functions, information-theory, average, entropy

I have $m$ vectors with i.i.d binary random symbols of the same length of $F$ bits. These vectors have a $70\%$ similarity with each other, (It means, for example, if the length of these vectors is $100$ bits, $70$ bits of them are exactly the same within all vectors). These vectors are clustered into $K$ clusters with considering the similarity between vectors with this constraint that the maximum distance (hamming distance)within each cluster be $\leq \Delta$. Now I want to calculate the function of conditional entropy of each vector within a cluster with its centroid and then make an average for all clusters. This function is related to the number of different bits between each vector and its centroid in the cluster. for example, if the number of different bits between vector $X_1$ its centroid $C_1$ in cluster 1 is $p=0.03$ then $H(X_1|C_1)=H(0.03)=-0.03\log0.3-(0.97)\log(0.97)$.

**My question is**, how I can take averaging for all the vectors over all the clusters since this value of $p$ could be different for each vector? I should take the average over $p$

I will be grateful if you can help me with this question.

Comment: the "70% similarity with each other" bit and the "if the length of these vectors is 100 bits, 70 bits of them are exactly the same within all vectors" example are a little confusing... Are we speaking of a pairwise similarity or a joint (global) ?  Could you give an example of (say) a 50% similiarty for small $m$, $F$?

Comment: @leonbloy by this similarity I mean pairwise similarity, for example, if we have m=2 vectors with F=10 bits if they have 50% similarity, they have the same symbol in 50% of the exact positions, that is; F1= 1011100101, F2=1011111010 (I just taak the first five bits as the similar bits for simplicity but the position does not matter)

Comment: @leonbloy, since you asked me about the type of similarity, would you please tell me what would it be the difference in the pairwise similarity and joint (global) similarity in binary vectors?

Comment: Take for example $a=(0 0 1 1)$ $b=(1 0 0 1)$ $c=(1 0 1 0)$ The have a pairwise Hamming distance (inverse of what you call "similarity"... I think)  of $2$ , hence a "50% similarity" (pairwise). But taken as a whole, it's false that "2 bits are exactly the same within all vectors". The only bit that is "the same within all vectors" is the second one.

Comment: @leonbloy  According to your example, I believe my question considers this assumption that some bits are the same within all vectors (like the second part of your example that only the second bit is the same within all the three vectors., I think in this case we can say that we 0.25 similarity between the vectors, right?)